# __doPostBack not working in safari or firefox, works in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, postback, dopostback

in my asp.net application, two buttons call a javascript function called refreshView, below is the function refreshView.

```
function RefreshView() {
                        __doPostBack('ButtonApply', '')
                        window.parent.location.href = "dashboardtree.aspx"
                    }
```

In IE, this is working correctly, but in firefox and safari the page refreshes (due to the window.parent.location) - but never calls the doPostBack (i was able to tell this using tracepoint and the sub that is called stores values to the database, the values are not being stored as well, sub is never hit). Below is the first line of the sub.

```
 Private Sub ButtonApply_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonApply.Click
```

Can anyone see why this would not work? I figured I could always replace the doPostBack with pageMethods and create a new sub/function - but I'd like to complete this the way it currently is. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't perform a redirect and postback at the same time in your JavaScript routine.  What you should do instead is to redirect after your postback logic has completed.  You will only know when it is completed in the Codebehind or if your Javascript received some sort of Asynchronous callback.  In its current state, your JavaScript routine has no idea when your Postback will complete.

You are creating a conflict.  What you are essentially doing is telling the page to post and at the very same time to redirect somewhere else.  In all likelihood, FireFox and Safari probably ignored the `__doPostBack()` because of this fact.

Here's what I would do instead:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string target = Request["__EVENTTARGET"];
  //if parameter equals "ButtonApply"
  //{       
  //    Do whatever, Then...
  //    Response.Redirect("dashboardtree.aspx"); <- you may need to modify the url depending on your structure
  //}
}
```

**EDIT**

```
...about the response.redirect - this will not work for me because the page that contains the post back, is an iframe inside another page...
```

Apologies, I missed the window.parent.

What I would recommend then is to use ajax.  In a nutshell, you would use ajax to place a call to a server-side method which would perform your logic (that you currently do in the postback).  Upon completion, the client will be notified in a callback when the process has completed (and whether or not it was successful).  Upon successful completion, you would perform your redirect.

There are several examples of this on the web, I'll provide a few for you:

- [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)
- [Using jQuery to Call ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods – By Example](http://weblogs.asp.net/craigshoemaker/archive/2008/11/07/using-jquery-to-call-asp-net-ajax-page-methods-by-example.aspx)
- [Call server side method from client side using script manager](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1276/call-server-side-method-from-client-side-using-script-manager/)

Comment: you are correct, removing the window.parent.location.href will allow the sub to be hit. Now how can I get the page to refresh just like if you hit the refresh button? Post back or not doesnt matter since the sub was hit using the doPostBack and stored the values I needed to the db, these values are pulled back in from the db during page load.

Comment: about the response.redirect - this will not work for me because the page that contains the post back, is an iframe inside another page, i used window.parent.location.href before for this, but what should i use instead? i need to refresh the parent, not the current.

Comment: Ah apologies, I missed the window.parent.  What would be best for you then is to use ajax to call a method to perform your processing in lieu of a postback.  You would then receive a callback from ajax upon completion.  Once you receive the ajax callback, then you would do the window.parent redirect.

Comment: so something like pageMethods to call the server side, then use the window.parent.redirect on its return? ill try this and post back most likely tomorrow. thank you for your help

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  In fact, you might be interested in the 3rd link I listed which includes an example of how to do that.

Comment: I was able to successfully complete this using this method. thank you for all of your help

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute a method after each postback is finished, you can add the method to the handlerlist via PageRequestManager. (see : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028)
After the method is executed you can remove it from the handler list if necessary.

```
function Reload() {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().remove_pageLoaded(Reload);
    window.parent.location.href = "dashboardtree.aspx";
}

function RefreshView() {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(Reload);
    __doPostBack('ButtonApply', '');
}
```